# How to wrap up my link with javascript onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have this link

```
<div class="new-div" ><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>
```

In this case user has to press on the title to get the link and I want also to wrap up div class with the link. Tried several variants. I think there should be a solution with javascript onclick function, but do not know actually how to wrap it up. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you mean javascript instead of java?

Comment: @Andrej: you are right - I changed the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="new-div" onclick="location.href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>
```

Comment: This was actually wrong, but I changed to     <div class="new-div" onclick="location.href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'"><?php the_title(); ?> and it worked. So, thanks.

Comment: @user919375 just know little php